# State Pattern Usage in parsing strings

Tags: java, parsing, state-pattern

> State pattern is useful while parsing String. A state means a part of
>   work, like a method. When you parse some words from the string you will change the state into
>   a new one

What does this means? I am really confused.

I have a string in this format "OPERATOR OBJECT [FILTER] [VALUES]"
and while parsing the query you should use State Pattern. There are four states: OPERATOR,OBJECT, FILTER and VALUES"

Comment: You should tell us where you found that statement...

Comment: This description does not seem to be really good, where did you get it from? I don't agree that a state is comparable to a method. A state in programming mostly refers to the values assigned to all variables of an object / class. The state pattern introduces an own type which encapsulates these values.

Comment: because of I am confused. I am thinking about this for 3 days...

Comment: its my assignment in uni

Answer (score 2):

I think that the author of your quote could refer to something like an *acceptor* of the automata theory which uses different states to store the current matching progress. To illustrate this, I will give an example. However, the states are not like methods, but they implement the same method in a different way.

```
/** Accepts strings which contain SO */
class Acceptor {

    private enum State {
        NOTHING_YET {
            @Override
            State nextState( char c ) {
                if(c == 'S') {
                    return FOUND_S;
                } else {
                    return NOTHING_YET;
                }
            }
        },
        FOUND_S {
            @Override
            State nextState( char c ) {
                if(c == 'O') {
                    return FOUND_SO;
                } else if(c == 'S') {
                    return FOUND_S;
                } else {
                    return NOTHING_YET;
                }
            }
        },
        FOUND_SO {
            @Override
            State nextState( char c ) {
                return FOUND_SO;
            }
        };

        abstract State nextState( char c );
    }


    boolean accept( String word ) {
        State current = State.NOTHING_YET;
        for(char c : word.toCharArray()) {
            current = current.nextState( c );
        }
        return current == State.FOUND_SO;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't think we should look for any words because our OPERATOR could be "set, get, update, add" and OBJECT could be "user, assignment" !!!

Comment: @Arira My answer was just a general interpretation of what could be meant by the quote you have posted. If you need more specific help on your task, please describe the task more in detail and add what you have tried to solve it and why your solution does not work. We are not here to guess and solve your problem, you need to also put effort in your question.